# Assign a list in a pandas dataframe cell: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to

```
df.at[100, 'subjects']
```

The result is

```
[]
```

which indicates the index is unique.

But when I tried to replace the empty list to a new one:

```
df.at[100, 'subjects'] = [1,2,3]
```

the error occurred.

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

I met several similar cases when I tried to assign a list value to a specific cell in pandas dataframe. But I couldn't repeat this error, sometimes the valueError showed up and at other times it was just fine. I really cannot explain the reason that has caused the difference..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you're using `.at` and not `.loc`? I searched for that error message, and usually changing `.loc` to `.at` fixes it.

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure. I copied and pasted the code which generated the error.

Comment: Check the type of the column, if it is int64 or float64 (numeric) you will have this error, however, if it is an object (string), the assignment should be alright with pd.at.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the length of the list [1,2,3] you are trying to assign to the cell ['subjects'] is not the same as the length of the index ['100'].

To resolve this error, ensure that the length of the list to be assigned is equal to the number of indices. In your case, the length of the index is 1 and the length of the list is 3. Therefore, you can either add more indices or reduce the length of the list to be assigned to one element.

You can try the following:

To add more indices:

```py
df.loc[[100, 101], 'subjects'] = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

To reduce the length of the list to be assigned:

```py
df.at[100, 'subjects'] = [1]
```

Both the above methods should work without raising the "ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable" error.